# Why does the org.hibernate.JDBCException not print the sql statement in a stacktrace

Tags: hibernate, exception, ora-00942

When an org.hibernate.JDBCException occurrs (or a Subtype of this Exception) the sql statement is not visible in the Stacktrace.

For Example if i execute the following SQL statement with hibernate (on an Oracle DB which does not have a table or view 'nonexsiting'):

```
session.createSQLQuery("select * from nonexisting").list();
```

i get the following stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist
    ...
```

The SQL statement is not shown in the stacktrace, however the Exception object has the information stored and can be accessed by `exception.getSQL()`. It would extremely speed up debugging if this information would be available in the stacktrace too.

Anybody an idea why this information is not available in the stacktrace? Or how to enable the output of this information in the stacktrace?

By the way the hibernate version i used for this example is 3.3.1

Comment: One way to get the information into the stacktrace is to rethrow the exception and putting the sql statement from the thrown exception information into the "message" part of the rethrown exception.

Still i see no reason why this is not done by default...

for example: throw new JDBCException(e.getMessage() + " " + e.getSQL(), e.getSQLException(), e.getSQL)

Still i see no reason why this is not done by default...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's not how it has been implemented. See [HB-1055](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HB-1055).

Spring and the classes implementing [`PersistenceExceptionTranslator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/dao/support/PersistenceExceptionTranslator.html) might provide something closer to your expectations.

Comment: Thanks Pascal for the answer. As far as i unterstand HB-1055 this is about capturing the SQL statement and provide this information via jdbcexception.getSQL(). My question however is more about why this method is not used when printing the stacktrace, as this would be a very valuable information.

Comment: @hochraldo: Because Gavin King chose to not put the SQL statement in the `message`, because that's not how he implemented it.

Comment: Okay got it. Still would be interesting to know why Gavin decided not to put this information in the stacktrace...

Comment: testing with Hibernate 4.3.7 (WildFly 8.2.1.Final, Postgres 9.3, JPA scenarios) I found that in my case `org.hibernate.JDBCException` or its derived counterpart `org.hibernate.SQLGrammarException` do not provide the underlying SQL via their `getSQL()` method :-(

Answer (score 2):

I assume that it could be a security issue. If you add the sql statement to the stack trace, it might be published to a user and so give him information about your table names and columns. If your application is vulnerable to sql injection, this would be a really big benefit for intruders.

Comment: Never considered this, but this seems evident to me. Thanks for this insight.

Comment: I can't agree. **A knife is not a bad thing just because somebody might be killed with it.** The benefit of having a causing (errenous) SQL in a log (which is normally not accessible by end users) of a running production system (and test systems etc.) is extremly helpful. Such issues might be hard or not at all to repeat and enabling logging of all SQL seems not a good alternative. Dumping the SQL to the end user seems rather unlikely having to get it via `getSQL()` explicitely (also for logging). If some dev did so - it won't harm security or politics in most cases anyways.